# Excel - Mutiple IFs in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Alright, the title is a hair misleading. First, I'm in Google Spreadsheet. Second, This more than a IF(condition, return IF(...)) kind of situation (Also, I was looking around to see if I could even post an excel formula question on this site... didn't see much so if this is not the proper place feel free to say so and I'll delete).

I have a table that I need to get a value from based on 2 cells:

```
   -3 -2 -1 0  1  2  3  4  5
  ___________________________
A| 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12,16
B| 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12,16,20
C| 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12,16,20,24
D| 1, 2, 4, 8, 12,16,20,24,28
```

I basically need C1 to equal what would be returned if A1 was "A", "B", "C", or "D" , and B1 was in the range of -3 - 5.

All of my attempts have been #error, so I don't have anything to show for the last hour I've put into figuring this out. I'm confident there's a way though. If you want my failed attempts let me know.

Comment: In your example, A is a numeric row, so what do you mean by 'if A1 was "A", "B", "C", or "D"'? Also, if your constraints are met, what should the value of C1 be? If not met, what should its value be?

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie It's going into a form for a user to fill out. Example: In A1 they can enter "A", and in B1 they can enter 3, and C1 will return 8. Otherwise, C1 should just be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your table is stored on the top left of `Sheet2`, then you can use the following formula in cell `C1`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$J$5,$B$1+5,FALSE),0)
```

The [`VLOOKUP`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) function looks up the row where your desired letter is (as given in `A1`). If it is found, it will return the value in the column indicated by the contents of `B1` with 5 added to transpose to the right value. The `FALSE` parameter indicates that the lookup should do an exact match.

If the value is not found, the [`IFERROR`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/iferror-function-HA010342587.aspx?CTT=1) wrapped around `VLOOKUP` will take care of inserting the `0`.

I shared [a Google Spreadsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsKgk0f08g0XdF9VN1RrZFhhMlkwSGpiSTV6aDY1THc&usp=sharing), with the formulas on `Sheet1` and the table on `Sheet2`.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it from returning the label? If -4 is entered at B1, "A" or "B" etc. is returned, which causes errors with other calculations on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Nvm, I just extended the table out and compensated by increasing the +5 in B1. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome. I did not think about the exception situation where -4 was entered. You could replace the expression `$B$1+5` with `IF($B$1>-4,$B$1+5,-1)`.

Comment: Additionally, you could use a drop-down list in cell B1 (and also in A1) to avoid erroneous input. See, for example, [this tutorial](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/ss/2011-09-05-excel-2010-data-validation-pt-1.htm). That is about "regular" Excel, but it works basically the same in Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: The drop down list would be a great idea, except in my case the cell representing the index is a formula as well. Thanks for all you're help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `INDEX` in array mode:

Assuming
data is in `$G$9:$O$12`
row labels (`A`..`D`) is in `$F$9:$F$12`
column labels in `$G$8:$O$8`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$9:$O$12,MATCH($A$1,$F$9:$F$12,0),MATCH($B$1,$G$8:$O$8,0)),0)
```

This has the advantage that it does not rely on the column headers being integers in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VLOOKUP`. For example, if you place the table at A5, make the following the formula for `C1`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,A5:J9,B1+5,FALSE)
```

(`A5:J9` is your lookup table; you can move it wherever, even on another sheet)